# getting the largest values from two grouped columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have counted the common occurrence from two columns with dplyr.

```
yelp_tbl %>% group_by(city, name) %>% count(city, name)

# A tibble: 126,968 x 3
# Groups:   city, name [126,968]
    city        name     n
   <chr>       <chr> <int>
 1   Toronto   Starbucks   132
 2 Las Vegas   Starbucks   129
 3 Las Vegas      Subway   107
 4 Las Vegas  McDonald's    79
 5   Phoenix   Starbucks    75
```

Now I want to filter the rows with the largest value (n) of the first and second column. This means I only want to keep the name/city combinations with the largest (n) so that each city appears only one time.

I tried:

```
yelp_tbl %>% group_by(city, name) %>% count(city, name) %>% top_n(1,n)
```

but it didn´t work. Thank you.

Data Frame:

```
> dput(yelp_tbl[ 1:20, ])
structure(list(business_id = c("0DI8Dt2PJp07XkVvIElIcQ", "LTlCaCGZE14GuaUXUGbamg", 
"EDqCEAGXVGCH4FJXgqtjqg", "cnGIivYRLxpF7tBVR_JwWA", "cdk-qqJ71q6P7TJTww_DSA", 
"Q9rsaUiQ-A3NdEAloy0aJA", "Cu4_Fheh7IrzGiK-Pc79ig", "GDnbt3isfhd57T1QqU6flg", 
"qwAHit4Tuj1zpO7CxVwOMA", "Nbr0kbtIrVlEcKIZoXWbSw", "MFneYHieJ_lnjMeFUGKVbw", 
"42romV8altAeuZuP2OC1gw", "iaunX_af5M5lfT2eEm9FMQ", "Tc24GX9-ZPr4_SHU0nJZZA", 
"6EvETd9FVPJfhT_6AW9iEw", "DSWsjtAfLYw9a4MTz0kKLw", "SbfEPi-iR4ntf3wRQfxYyw", 
"YCsLfBVdLFeN2Necw1HPSA", "O_4OTnw48ULP5uZh6MqiOQ", "CE0dABv9sfrXjDIJugpU8A"
), name = c("Innovative Vapors", "Cut and Taste", "Pizza Pizza", 
"Plush Salon and Spa", "Comfort Inn", "A Plus Nail", "Boomerang Baby", 
"Taco Bell", "CubeSmart Self Storage", "Sehne Backwaren", "Revv Illusions", 
"Ohana Hawaiian BBQ", "Encore Books and Records", "Canyon Ridge Endodontics", 
"Fossil Store", "Best Buy", "Woofs, Wiggles N Wags All Breed Rescue", 
"Stussy", "Holiday Inn Express & Suites Madison Central", "Graceful Cake Creations"
), neighborhood = c("", "", "Dufferin Grove", "", "Downtown Core", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Notre-Dame-de-Grâce", "", "", "", 
"", "Ossington Strip", "", ""), address = c("227 E Baseline Rd, Ste J2", 
"495 S Grand Central Pkwy", "979 Bloor Street W", "7014 Steubenville Pike", 
"321 Jarvis Street", "30 Gibson Drive, Suite122", "10875 N Frankloyd Wright Blvd", 
"11072 No Frank Lloyd Wright", "11000 North 115th Street", "Hauptstr. 1", 
"2553 Wigwam Pkwy", "1500 N Green Valley Pkwy, Ste 230", "5670 Sherbrooke Rue W", 
"2525 W Carefree Hwy", "6801 North Lake Mall Drive, 173", "2500 Winston Park Drive, Unit A", 
"", "1000 Queen Street W", "610 John Nolen Dr", "330 S Gilbert Rd, Ste 15"
), city = c("Tempe", "Las Vegas", "Toronto", "Oakdale", "Toronto", 
"Markham", "Scottsdale", "Scottsdale", "Scottsdale", "Stuttgart", 
"Henderson", "Henderson", "Montréal", "Phoenix", "Charlotte", 
"Oakville", "Scottsdale", "Toronto", "Madison", "Mesa"), state = c("AZ", 
"NV", "ON", "PA", "ON", "ON", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "BW", "NV", "NV", 
"QC", "AZ", "NC", "ON", "AZ", "ON", "WI", "AZ"), postal_code = c("85283", 
"89106", "M6H 1L5", "15071", "M5B 2C2", "L3R 2S3", "85259", "85259", 
"85259", "70563", "89074", "89074", "H4A 1W7", "85085", "28216", 
"L6H 7E5", "", "M6J 1H1", "53713", "85204"), latitude = c(33.3782141, 
36.1922841, 43.661054, 40.4445439533, 43.6598286, 43.82764, 33.5852707, 
33.58671, 33.5864403, 48.7299, 36.0345795, 36.029596485, 45.4707675, 
33.7967745, 35.3521284, 43.5162547833, 33.6031328399, 43.644258153, 
43.048623, 33.4091719), longitude = c(-111.936102, -115.1592718, 
-79.429089, -80.1745398943, -79.3754006, -79.342722, -111.8349538, 
-111.83541, -111.8325788, 9.11242, -115.0977701, -115.085821152, 
-73.6150299, -112.1154511, -80.8512352, -79.6859058738, -111.971311071, 
-79.4188293813, -89.376341, -111.7884179), stars = c(4.5, 5, 
2.5, 4, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 4.5, 3.5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3.5, 3, 4.5, 
2, 4.5, 5), review_count = c(17L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 
11L, 3L, 7L, 38L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 17L, 5L, 14L, 7L), is_open = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), attributes = list(c("BikeParking: True", "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin: False", 
"BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}", 
"DogsAllowed: False", "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2", "WheelchairAccessible: True"
), c("BusinessAcceptsBitcoin: False", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True"
), c("Alcohol: none", "Ambience: {'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': False}", 
"BikeParking: True", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}", 
"Caters: True", "GoodForKids: True", "GoodForMeal: {'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': False, 'breakfast': False, 'brunch': False}", 
"HasTV: True", "NoiseLevel: quiet", "OutdoorSeating: False", 
"RestaurantsAttire: casual", "RestaurantsDelivery: True", "RestaurantsGoodForGroups: True", 
"RestaurantsPriceRange2: 1", "RestaurantsReservations: False", 
"RestaurantsTableService: False", "RestaurantsTakeOut: True", 
"WiFi: free"), c("AcceptsInsurance: False", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", 
"BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}", 
"ByAppointmentOnly: True", "HairSpecializesIn: {'coloring': False, 'africanamerican': False, 'curly': False, 'perms': False, 'kids': False, 'extensions': False, 'asian': False, 'straightperms': False}", 
"RestaurantsPriceRange2: 3"), c("BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", 
"RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2", "WiFi: free"), c("BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", 
"ByAppointmentOnly: True", "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 3"), c("BikeParking: True", 
"BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}", 
"RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2", "WheelchairAccessible: True"), c("Alcohol: none", 
"Ambience: {'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': False}", 
"BikeParking: True", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}", 
"DriveThru: True", "GoodForKids: True", "GoodForMeal: {'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': False, 'breakfast': False, 'brunch': False}", 
"HasTV: False", "NoiseLevel: quiet", "OutdoorSeating: False", 
"RestaurantsAttire: casual", "RestaurantsDelivery: False", "RestaurantsGoodForGroups: True", 
"RestaurantsPriceRange2: 1", "RestaurantsReservations: False", 
"RestaurantsTableService: False", "RestaurantsTakeOut: True", 
"WiFi: no"), "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", c("BikeParking: True", 
"BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: False", "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}", 
"RestaurantsDelivery: False", "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 3", "RestaurantsTakeOut: True"
), NULL, c("Alcohol: none", "Ambience: {'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}", 
"BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}", 
"Caters: True", "GoodForKids: True", "GoodForMeal: {'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': True, 'dinner': True, 'breakfast': False, 'brunch': False}", 
"HasTV: True", "NoiseLevel: quiet", "OutdoorSeating: False", 
"RestaurantsAttire: casual", "RestaurantsDelivery: False", "RestaurantsGoodForGroups: True", 
"RestaurantsPriceRange2: 1", "RestaurantsReservations: False", 
"RestaurantsTableService: False", "RestaurantsTakeOut: True", 
"WiFi: no"), c("BikeParking: True", "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}", 
"RestaurantsPriceRange2: 1"), "ByAppointmentOnly: True", NULL, 
    c("BikeParking: True", "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", 
    "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}", 
    "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2"), NULL, c("BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", 
    "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}", 
    "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 3"), c("BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", 
    "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2", "WiFi: free"), c("BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True", 
    "BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}", 
    "RestaurantsDelivery: True", "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2", 
    "RestaurantsTakeOut: True", "WheelchairAccessible: True")), 
    categories = list(c("Tobacco Shops", "Nightlife", "Vape Shops", 
    "Shopping"), c("Caterers", "Grocery", "Food", "Event Planning & Services", 
    "Party & Event Planning", "Specialty Food"), c("Restaurants", 
    "Pizza", "Chicken Wings", "Italian"), c("Hair Removal", "Beauty & Spas", 
    "Blow Dry/Out Services", "Hair Stylists", "Hair Extensions", 
    "Massage", "Permanent Makeup", "Waxing", "Hair Salons"), 
        c("Hotels & Travel", "Event Planning & Services", "Hotels"
        ), c("Nail Salons", "Beauty & Spas"), c("Baby Gear & Furniture", 
        "Shopping"), c("Tex-Mex", "Mexican", "Fast Food", "Restaurants"
        ), c("Local Services", "Self Storage"), c("Food", "Bakeries"
        ), c("Nail Salons", "Hair Salons", "Beauty & Spas"), 
        c("Hawaiian", "Restaurants", "Barbeque"), c("Shopping", 
        "Bookstores", "Books", "Mags", "Music & Video"), c("General Dentistry", 
        "Health & Medical", "Dentists"), c("Leather Goods", "Fashion", 
        "Watches", "Accessories", "Shopping"), c("Mobile Phones", 
        "Computers", "Local Services", "Electronics", "IT Services & Computer Repair", 
        "Shopping"), c("Animal Shelters", "Pets"), c("Shoe Stores", 
        "Fashion", "Men's Clothing", "Shopping"), c("Hotels & Travel", 
        "Venues & Event Spaces", "Event Planning & Services", 
        "Hotels"), c("Food", "Bakeries")), hours = list(c("Monday 11:0-21:0", 
    "Tuesday 11:0-21:0", "Wednesday 11:0-21:0", "Thursday 11:0-21:0", 
    "Friday 11:0-22:0", "Saturday 10:0-22:0", "Sunday 11:0-18:0"
    ), c("Monday 0:0-0:0", "Tuesday 0:0-0:0", "Wednesday 0:0-0:0", 
    "Thursday 0:0-0:0", "Friday 0:0-0:0", "Saturday 0:0-0:0", 
    "Sunday 0:0-0:0"), c("Monday 11:0-2:0", "Tuesday 11:0-2:0", 
    "Wednesday 11:0-2:0", "Thursday 11:0-3:0", "Friday 11:0-3:0", 
    "Saturday 11:0-3:0", "Sunday 11:0-2:0"), c("Tuesday 10:0-21:0", 
    "Wednesday 10:0-21:0", "Thursday 10:0-21:0", "Friday 10:0-18:0", 
    "Saturday 9:0-16:0"), NULL, c("Monday 10:30-20:0", "Tuesday 10:30-20:0", 
    "Thursday 10:30-20:0", "Friday 10:30-20:0", "Saturday 10:30-19:0", 
    "Sunday 10:30-19:0"), c("Monday 10:0-18:0", "Tuesday 10:0-18:0", 
    "Wednesday 10:0-18:0", "Thursday 10:0-18:0", "Friday 10:0-18:0", 
    "Saturday 10:0-18:0", "Sunday 11:0-16:0"), c("Monday 10:0-22:0", 
    "Tuesday 10:0-22:0", "Wednesday 10:0-22:0", "Thursday 10:0-22:0", 
    "Friday 10:0-22:0", "Saturday 10:0-22:0", "Sunday 10:0-22:0"
    ), c("Monday 9:30-18:0", "Tuesday 9:30-18:0", "Wednesday 9:30-18:0", 
    "Thursday 9:30-18:0", "Friday 9:30-18:0", "Saturday 8:30-17:0", 
    "Sunday 11:0-15:0"), NULL, c("Monday 8:0-19:0", "Tuesday 8:0-19:0", 
    "Wednesday 8:0-19:0", "Thursday 8:0-19:0", "Friday 8:0-19:0", 
    "Saturday 8:0-17:0", "Sunday 10:0-13:0"), c("Monday 11:0-21:30", 
    "Tuesday 11:0-21:30", "Wednesday 11:0-21:30", "Thursday 11:0-21:30", 
    "Friday 11:0-21:30", "Saturday 11:0-21:30", "Sunday 11:30-21:0"
    ), c("Monday 11:0-19:0", "Tuesday 11:0-19:0", "Wednesday 11:0-19:0", 
    "Thursday 11:0-21:0", "Friday 11:0-21:0", "Saturday 11:0-19:0", 
    "Sunday 11:0-19:0"), NULL, c("Monday 10:0-21:0", "Tuesday 10:0-21:0", 
    "Wednesday 10:0-21:0", "Thursday 10:0-21:0", "Friday 10:0-22:0", 
    "Saturday 10:0-22:0", "Sunday 11:0-19:0"), c("Monday 10:0-21:0", 
    "Tuesday 10:0-21:0", "Wednesday 10:0-21:0", "Thursday 10:0-21:0", 
    "Friday 10:0-21:0", "Saturday 10:0-21:0", "Sunday 11:0-18:0"
    ), NULL, NULL, c("Monday 0:0-0:0", "Tuesday 0:0-0:0", "Wednesday 0:0-0:0", 
    "Thursday 0:0-0:0", "Friday 0:0-0:0", "Saturday 0:0-0:0", 
    "Sunday 0:0-0:0"), c("Monday 9:0-16:0", "Tuesday 9:0-16:0", 
    "Wednesday 9:0-16:0", "Thursday 9:0-16:0", "Friday 9:0-16:0", 
    "Saturday 10:0-15:0", "Sunday 10:0-15:0")), type = c("business", 
    "business", "business", "business", "business", "business", 
    "business", "business", "business", "business", "business", 
    "business", "business", "business", "business", "business", 
    "business", "business", "business", "business")), .Names = c("business_id", 
"name", "neighborhood", "address", "city", "state", "postal_code", 
"latitude", "longitude", "stars", "review_count", "is_open", 
"attributes", "categories", "hours", "type"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `yelp_tbl %>% group_by(city, name) %>% count(city, name) %>% select(city, n) %>% group_by(city)%>% filter(n == max(n))`

Let me know if it works else provide toy structure.

Comment: Does this work for you? `yelp_tbl %>% group_by(city, name) %>% count(city, name)%>%group_by(city)%>%top_n(1)`

Comment: I edited it again. Try this.

Would you mind to provide me toy dataframe, use `dput(yelp_tbl[ 1:100, ])`

Comment: With both commands, I get `A tibble: 8,581 x 3'. But I have 878 unique cities in my data frame.

Comment: @Hadsga provide me toy dataframe use `dput` as I mentioned in my previous comment and edit your question. Paste there, the output you get in R console.

Comment: @Hadsga `df%>%select(city,name)%>%count()%>%ungroup()%>%group_by(city)%>%filter(n == max(n, na.rm = T))` , try this, output city column have unique city name.

Comment: @Hadsga Are there many cities with multiple names that have the same top n value? `top_n()` returns all such combinations , which may account for  your results. If so, try something like `yelp %>% group_by(city, name) %>% count(city, name) %>% group_by(city) %>% arrange(n) %>% mutate(r = rank(-n, ties.method = "random")) %>% filter(r == 1) %>% select(-r)` to break the ties.